# Is it possible to disable `ypcat passwd`

Tags: network, linux, password-management

We have an old NIS setup which, at geological speed, is being replaced by a Kerberos one. In the meantime, all the (non-root) users can simply type `ypcat passwd` and get the hashes of all the users' passwords. Is there an interim hack one can do to mitigate this so that it is at least not trivial to get the password hashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade to NIS+, but that's sort of an epic definition of "interim hack."

No, plain old NIS does not support any protection for the password hashes it distributes.

(and before someone suggests removing or chmod'ing ypcat, you'd have to disable every programming language on the system as well.  Writing a ypcat clone is trivial, see [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/nis.html) for example.)